# Should I wrap all functions that defined in component in useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

As far as I've known, functions that defined in a React's functional component are regenerated whenever the component rerenders. Since useCallback can be triggered by specific dependencies, it prevents unnecessary regeneration of these functions. Should I wrap each of them in useCallback, and pass relevant dependencies?

```
import React from 'react'

const Comp = () => {
   const fn1 = useCallback(
     ()=>{
      // do something
　　　}, [dependency1])

   const fn2 = useCallback(
     ()=>{
      // do something
　　　}, [dependency2])

   return (
      //something
   )
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`useCallback` will help in avoiding regeneration of functions when the functional component re-renders. However there isn't much of a performance difference caused by recreation of functions.

Using useCallback should be preferred in the following cases

1. If you are passing the function on to child component as props and the child component doesn't often need re-rendering except when a certain prop change then useCallback might prevent certain re-renders. However if you state is complex and you need multiple such functions to be passed on to children as props, it better to shift to `useReducer` instead of `useState` and pass on the `dispatch` method to child components
2. You are specifying a function as a dependency to `useEffect`. In such as case you must ensure that the function in not recreated on every render or the `useEffect` will be triggered on every render.

Overall a decision to use `useCallback` must be made judiciously instead of blindly since you might just overdo the advantage offered by `useCallback` and end up degrading the performance since `useCallback` will also memoize the functions and a frequently changing dependency might anyways need to recreate the function.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding another case to the above answer.
Sometimes you might have a function with a heavy computing and you probably don't want it to calculate the result on every render so in that case you would also use `useCallback`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: for heavy computing, you'd use `useMemo` not `useCallback` right

Comment: @Embedded_Mugs it depends. If you want to get a value back you need to use `useMemo` but if you just need to run a function then you would use `useCallback`